# Expectation with indicator function disjoint sets

Tags: probability, probability-theory

This might be a very silly question, but I havent found the answer yet. consider a probability space $(X, P, F)$, and a set $\Omega \in F$ which is the union of $N$ disjoint sets $\Omega = \Omega_1 \cup \Omega_2 ...\cup \Omega_N$ where $\Omega_i \cap \Omega_j = \emptyset$ for $i \neq j$.

I need to compute the expectation of

$\mathbb{E}[X  \mathbb{1}_{\Omega}]$

Where $\mathbb{1}_\Omega$ is the indicator function of set $\Omega$. Is the following true?

$\mathbb{E}[X  \mathbb{1}_{\Omega}]=\sum_{i=1}^N \mathbb{E} [X \mathbb{1}_{\Omega_i}]$

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Yes… it holds $$1_\Omega = \sum_{i=1}^N 1_{\Omega_i}$$ now use linearity of the expectation to get: $$\mathbb{E}[X  \mathbb{1}_{\Omega}]= \mathbb{E}[X   \sum_{i=1}^N 1_{\Omega_i}] = \sum_{i=1}^N \mathbb{E} [X \mathbb{1}_{\Omega_i}]$$

Btw… the in the probability space you consider the sample space in the first place and not a r.v.
If X is the sample space $E[X]$ makes no sense... but I guess you just messed up notations.

Comment: Yes, I messed up with the notation, my apologies. Thank you very much for your answer